# Compartilhar Link com Imagem no Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web, seo

Gostaria de saber como faço para colar um link em um post do Facebook e ele mostrar uma imagem. Por exemplo: se eu colar o link do Twitter em um post, ele coloca uma imagem, seguido pelo título e descrição da página do URL (no caso, o Twitter). Como eu faço para ter essa imagem no meu link também?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando metas `og:`

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

Comment: Amigo, eu estava usando essas tags, mas não estavam funcionando... Então acessei o link que você passou e vi que eu precisava só depurar a URL (através do https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ ) para ele atualizar os dados... Agora está tudo funcionando perfeitamente como eu precisava. MUITO obrigado! :D

Answer (score 0):

Para isso, você precisa que o seu link tenha uma imagem em seu conteúdo. O facebook pega automaticamente a imagem no conteudo de sua página e a anexa à exibição do seu post do fb.

Mas você pode também alterar a imagem, o facebook te dá essa possibilidade também.

Ocorre que, se é uma postagem de um blog, parece que há um cache ou do facebook ou do servidor do blog que, ao tentar postar no facebook imediatamente após a publicação do post, ele não reconhece a imagem, tendo que esperar um tempo para publicar.

Mas tendo a imagem reconhecida, você pode mantê-la ou alterá-la também, ficando ao seu critério.

Comment: Na verdade não tem imagens no link... É um app online com base em um canvas... Aí acaba não tendo imagens... Se eu colocar uma imagem e via CSS configurar ela com display hidden o Facebook consegue identificá-la?

Answer (score 0):

1. Relacionar o item

Refazendo minha Resposta 
Primeiro é preciso entender como o Facebook trabalha com com  URL canônica.
ex você tem uma pagina www.suapagina.com/faleconosco.php e dentro dessa pagina vc tem um monte de meta tag teoricamente o facebook procura as  meta tag nesta pagina e também as 
 obrigado pela colaboração dos colegas sou enfermeiro de carreira mas trabalho com desenvolvimento de sistemas graças a espaços de compartilhamento de conhecimento

Answer (score -2):

tive esse mesmo problema para resolver tudo começa em 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwcarros.com%2F33 essa feramenta faz a verificação e apaga o cache do facebook se não encontrar uma tag og: ele usa uma tag comum e a imagem eu coloque uma imagem no head e deu display name pra ela o facebook reconheçeu mas as tais tag og: ele não reconheceu nem a pau 2 dias fuçando e nada a solução foi essa a e tem mais vc precisa ter uma URL URL canônica que aponte para onde estão as tag 
ex vc tem uma pagina index e compartinha essa pagina vc precisa colocar as tag onde a URL canônica aponta pode ate mesmo ser para outra pagina mas é onde a facebook vai buscar o titulo a descrição e a url alem da imagem se não tiver declarado certinho em tag ele escolhe o primeiro texto com tag que achar ou seja vira uma bagunça vc compartinha uma laranja ele mostra uma bicicleta

Comment: Não entendi direito o seu texto. Edite-o colocando a pontuação para ficar mais fácil de entender, pois está difícil entender o que você quis dizer. Deu para entender que tem que ver a URL canônica e a tag og e que se não esstiver correto, ele vai bagunçar. Mas ainda assim não consegui acompanhar o seu texto. De qualquer forma, seja bem-vindo a nossa comunidade.

Comment: Ah, só para esclarecer, não fui eu quem negativou a sua resposta.